# How to include unobtrusive javascript validation in your HtmlHelpers?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, unobtrusive-validation

I have written my own HtmlHelper and now want to integrate Unobtrusive Validation (e.g. http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html)

Is there a quick way to do this, to save interrogating the Model's Property's attributes and adding the `data-val-etc` HTML attributes to the HTML string that is built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes()` method is used in the MVC3 source:

See:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416607(v=vs.98).aspx
- System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.cs:371

Answer (score 0):

Appending the output of Html.ValidateFor() for the specific field should take care of it.   Generally the ValidateFor() just outputs the validation logic and messages for a specific field.  I may be missing something based on how I interpreted your question, but if I understand correctly that should solve it.

Comment: `Html.ValidateFor()` returns `void` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703548.aspx), how would you get the output of it?

Comment: Ah yeah, I guess trapping the output wouldn't be possible, as it writes directly to the response.  You didn't post the code for your HTML Helper, but would it be possible to inline the @Html.ValidateFor(m=>m.whateverproperty) in your custom Helper?

Comment: You can also try @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.property), this will output a string, check out the following post :                                                                     http://forums.asp.net/t/1524345.aspx/1?MVC+2+RC2+Clientside+validation+Html+ValidationMessageFor+required+even+if+using+DataAnnotations+

Comment: `@` syntax is part of RAZOR, the HtmlHelper a compiled C# class in another file that is called from the view. The ValidationMessageFor() provides the label etc, these are needed, but this won't solve the validation problem since the `data-val` attributes aren't there to allow the validation to run.

Comment: Ok I see what your saying, sorry for the miscommunication.  In this instance, you may want to download the MVC3 source and copy out the segment of Html.Validate that writes out the attributes and add that functionality to the output of your helper.   That would at least get you around having to figure out the logic yourself.  I can't think of any other way at the moment.